# Count number of occurrences of a date range

Tags: mysql

I am working on mysql select query with the ultimate goal of getting an integer based on the count of a subset from a pre-defined date range.

Scenario has a few constraints I can't seem to navigate in a clean way. For the sake of being concise, lets make an assumption that I am working with data for a membership organization. The basics of my situation include:

1. A user joins on a date (later referenced as 'join_date' and stored in my database in a datefield in format 'yyyy-mm-dd')
2. My calendar is based on two periods: a Fall Semester and a Spring Semester (names may be a little misleading). Within the calendar year, the Spring semester is defined as February 16 through September 15, while the Fall semester is defined as September 16 though February 15 (into the next year).
3. When a user joins, for the purposes of counting for this query, **the next** semester is considered the first semester. (i.e. joining on January 5 (Fall) means that users first semester will be Spring of that year, while joining on September 20 (Fall) means that users first semester will be Spring of the next year.

Back to my query needs. Relative to the **next semester** from the current date, I need to calculate the number of Fall + Spring semesters that remain before the eighth semester (including that eighth semester). i.e., If I join on April 1, 2016, my first semester would be Fall 2016, and my eighth would be Spring 2020. As of the current date (today = 2017-07-17), I need to get a count of 6 returned, which would represent Fall 2017, Spring 2018, Fall 2018, Spring 2019, Fall 2019, and Spring 2020.

A few other examples:

- Join 2016-01-01, 1st semester is Spring 2016, 8th semester is Fall 2019, remaining count needed to return is 5.
- Join 2016-10-01, 1st semester is Spring 2017, 8th semester is Fall 2020, remaining count needed to return is 7.

I have been using CASE statements to help break this down, but I am a novice and do not know if this is the best approach. It is *strongly* preferred to do this dynamically and not have to to use a staging table or similar, in which case it would be easy. My current CASE statements, which seem to work include:

```
CASE 
WHEN DATE_FORMAT( join_date, '%m/%d' ) BETWEEN '01/01' AND '02/14' THEN CONCAT( 'Spring ', YEAR ( join_date) ) 
WHEN DATE_FORMAT( join_date, '%m/%d' ) BETWEEN '02/15' AND '09/14' THEN CONCAT( 'Fall ', YEAR ( join_date) ) 
WHEN DATE_FORMAT( join_date, '%m/%d' ) BETWEEN '09/15' AND '12/31' THEN CONCAT( 'Spring ', YEAR ( join_date) + 1 ) 
END AS '1st semester'

CASE
WHEN DATE_FORMAT( join_date, '%m/%d' ) BETWEEN '01/01' AND '02/14' THEN CONCAT( 'Fall ', YEAR ( join_date) + 3 ) 
WHEN DATE_FORMAT( join_date, '%m/%d' ) BETWEEN '02/15' AND '09/14' THEN CONCAT( 'Spring ', YEAR ( join_date) + 4 ) 
WHEN DATE_FORMAT( join_date, '%m/%d' ) BETWEEN '09/15' AND '12/31' THEN CONCAT( 'Fall ', YEAR ( join_date ) + 4 ) 
END AS '8th semester'

CASE
WHEN DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE( ), '%m/%d' ) BETWEEN '01/01' AND '02/14' THEN CONCAT( 'Fall ', YEAR ( CURDATE( ) ) - 1 )
WHEN DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE( ), '%m/%d' ) BETWEEN '02/15' AND '09/14' THEN CONCAT( 'Spring ', YEAR ( CURDATE( ) ) )
WHEN DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE( ), '%m/%d' ) BETWEEN '09/15' AND '12/31' THEN CONCAT( 'Fall ', YEAR ( CURDATE( ) ) )
END AS 'current semester'

CASE
WHEN DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE( ), '%m/%d' ) BETWEEN '01/01' AND '02/14' THEN CONCAT( 'Spring ', YEAR ( CURDATE( ) ) )
WHEN DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE( ), '%m/%d' ) BETWEEN '02/15' AND '09/14' THEN CONCAT( 'Fall ', YEAR ( CURDATE( ) ) )
WHEN DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE( ), '%m/%d' ) BETWEEN '09/15' AND '12/31' THEN CONCAT( 'Spring ', YEAR ( CURDATE( ) ) + 1 )
END AS 'next semester'
```

Ultimately, I need find the count of the 'remaining semesters'

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. You can find a sample of a few user examples at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01319.

The expected result for these examples would be to get 2 for user 3060457, 5 for user 3060458, 6 for user 3060459, and 7 for user 3060460.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: An example has been provided in sqlfiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01319.